# Make table query on Crosstab query basis

Tags: sql-server, vba, database, ms-access, sql-server-2012

I am on migration from MS Access 2007 to SQL Server 2012 express. Recently I am faced with strange Access frontend behavor.

In one of our Apps based on MS Access I simulate Excel style to enter Employee working hours data on continuous form. On Open event subroutine prepares recordset for this form. In Soubroutine I have three MakeTable queries where I pass four parameters to each of them. All queries are based on Crosstab queries accordingly. I have saved all queries so I call them in subroutine by names (set querydef and pass all parameters).

But may problem is not actually related to Subroutine:

All MakeTable queries executes *without error*. However, only first table has records. Other two are empty.

- If I pass parameters manualy to each Crosstab query I see records in all three of them.
- If I pass parameters manualy to each MakeTable query I see records only in first made Table. Two others are empty!

And most interesting is that it appiers only with SQL Server BackEnd. If I do all steps with MS Access BackEnd all works just fine!

Comment: Try adding `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to your SQL Server connection string and try again.

Comment: Thank you but could you please explain where I should use it? May ConnString="ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=(local); DATABASE=STRDAT;Trusted_Connection=Yes"

Comment: Just add it at the end of your connection string: `ConnString="ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=(local); DATABASE=STRDAT;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=True`"

Comment: Scoregraphic, thanks for advise but it does not work. This is my connStr after edit: "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0; SERVER=(local);DATABASE=STRDAT; Trusted_Connection=Yes; MultipleActiveResultSets=tr‌​ue" I put "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" indtead of "SQL Server" as a driver. Maybe I need specific driver to be installed? Or it just does not work?

Comment: Have you tried `Provider=SQLNCLI11;` as provider instead of `DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0` Do you get a connection with this?

Comment: I use DSNless conection. When I put Provider=SQLNCLI11 instead of DRIVER I get "Open DSN file" dialogue. Have you idea how to do it in DSNless manier?

Comment: There is a brilliant site for connection string issues. www.connectionstrings.com. Try the MARS-connection string found on and be sure you use the server name with SQL Server 2012: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-odbc-driver/

Comment: According to your problem i think it's more an Access process problem that SQL problem. Access only run batch process, and haven't more than one thread, so Windows have more than one and sometimes appear process paralelized. Only try to put DoEvents (sometimes i put two times same command) after each call to SQL and retrieve results.

Comment: Scoregraphic, thank you for the link.
Mastercafe, I agree with you that maybe its happens on Access side. But the issue seems not even in VBA code. I cannot get records when I run single maketable query through UI. Crosstab wuery shows records well. On other side all works well with MS Access BE...

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Just added GROUP BY in 2 maketable queries. 
Still strange issue as GROUP BY is needed only with SQL Server BackEnd.

```
PARAMETERS strMon Text ( 255 ), strDep Text ( 255 ), strEmp Text ( 255 ), strPam Text ( 255 );
TRANSFORM First(tbl_Tabel.GR0) AS strValue
SELECT tbl_Employee.EmplCodeID AS EmplCodeID1, tbl_Tabel.TabWHrsID, tbl_TabelWHrs.TabWHrs
FROM tbl_Employee LEFT JOIN (tbl_Tabel LEFT JOIN tbl_TabelWHrs ON tbl_Tabel.TabWHrsID = tbl_TabelWHrs.TabWHrsID) ON tbl_Employee.EmplCodeID = tbl_Tabel.EmplCodeID
WHERE (((IIf([strEmp]="AAAA","AAAA",[tbl_Employee]![EmplCodeID]))=[strEmp]) AND ((IIf([strDep]="AAA","AAA",[Dep]))=[strDep]) AND ((IIf([strPam]="AA","AA",[tbl_Employee]![FacSubID]))=[strPam]) AND ((tbl_TabelWHrs.TabMon)=[strMon]) AND ((tbl_Employee.EndOfAgr)>=LastDayLastMonthCust(DateSerial(Left([strMon],4),Right([strmon],2),"01")) Or (tbl_Employee.EndOfAgr) Is Null))
GROUP BY tbl_Employee.EmplCodeID, tbl_Tabel.TabWHrsID, tbl_TabelWHrs.TabWHrs
ORDER BY DatePart("d",[TabDate])
PIVOT DatePart("d",[TabDate]) IN ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31");
```

Comment: I know you solved your issue but I wonder if you used the IN () clause on the PIVOT statement in Access. Usually, reports and other queries behave better when you explicitly state the column headers. Also, adding a GROUP BY in a crosstab would change the structure and result unless the group by column is shared by all records. I may look carefully at the results.

Comment: I use IN clause and GROUP BY on all fields. Pls. find my SQL string above (I cannot paste it in comments).